# How can I show "empty" if data is not there?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Because of this

```
<v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ vc_rule.url }}</v-card-subtitle>
```

where this.vc_rule could be `empty` or `null`. Sometimes, I got this error on my console.

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Instead of getting this error, how can I tell Vue.js to show "empty" if data is not there?

I envision something like this :

***Hint***: `?`

```
<v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ vc_rule?.url }}</v-card-subtitle>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) like this :

```js
<v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ vc_rule?.url ?? 'empty' }}</v-card-subtitle>
```

Comment: Give me a crash when I tried your codes.

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: Here : https://i.imgur.com/FNs7flW.png

Comment: If you still had this issue even after reloading your bundler you can try `{{vc_rule.url === undefined ? 'empty' : vc_rule.url` instead. I don't really understand the error, maybe your developement environment isn't updated to use optional chaining and/or nullish coalescing operator

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Logical_OR -> ||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      vc_rule: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ vc_rule?.url || 'empty' }}</v-card-subtitle>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, we can achieve that in the HTML template itself via use of [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) along with [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      vc_rule: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-card-subtitle class="py-0 my-0">{{ vc_rule?.url ?? 'empty' }}</v-card-subtitle>
</div>
```